# Using variables in simple PostgresSQL queries

Tags: postgresql

I have to perfrom a lot of queries where the same value is being reused. I thought of something like:

```sql
varName = 'value';
select * from sometable t where
 t.field1 = varName 
 or t.field2 = varName;
```

How can this be done with PostgreSQL 12?

I tried a lot of stuff I found, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What client application or programming library do you use to run the query?

Comment: plain simple sql, but I found a solution now by experimenting

Comment: [Write an answer then](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `VALUES` inside of your CTE. This will enable you to have multiple values in the same "variable".

Data Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t (c1 int, c2 text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'foo'),(1,'xpto');
```

Query

```
WITH j (var) AS (VALUES ('foo'),('bar')) 
SELECT t.c1,j.var FROM t
JOIN j ON j.var = t.c2;

 c1 | var 
----+-----
 42 | foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution meanwhile

```sql
with varName as (select 'value'::text) 
select * from sometable t where
 t.field1 = (select * from varName)
 or t.field2 = (select * from varName);
```

Comment: alternatively you can use `WITH varname ( VALUES ('value1'),('value2'),...) ...`. If you're interested, I can add another answer

Comment: @JimJones I tried this, but this did not work out

Comment: I just added an answer to make my point clearer

Comment: @JimJones ok, it turned out that I missed the correct syntax. yields the same result.

Comment: It indeed does. The only difference is that using this other approach you avoid the multiple subselects and you're able to have multiple values inside your variable. +1 and cheers